# How to load iframe using POST with header

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, iframe, header

I had a requirement to load a webpage into an iframe. The webpage server is secured by Open ID Connect and required a bearer token to be authorised. There are also data required to be send over the server for the page to be rendered. The content of the response also has some JavaScript. Iframe src only allow to have one URL which use GET method which does not offer what we wanted.

So in summary, I need to:

- Load webpage into iframe using POST
- Include token in Authorsation header.
- Load javascript once the page has been loaded in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took was use AJAX post to load the content of the page html and JavaScript. Once I have the content we write the content into the iframe contentwindows. 
There are alternative approach Ilooked into: 
- Using form post. This does not allow to include Token into Authorisation Header
- Using jQuery html method. This does not trigger to iframe to load the html. So JavaScript in the return page didnt works.

Working Example:https://jsfiddle.net/duongthaiha/wmLsrfo0/52/

Here is some code snippet:

```js
function loadHTMLToIframe(data) {
        alert(data);
        var iframe = document.getElementById('targetIframe');
        var iframedoc = iframe.document;
        if (iframe.contentDocument)
            iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument;
        else if (iframe.contentWindow)
            iframedoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

        if (iframedoc){
            // write content to the iframe
            iframedoc.open();
            iframedoc.writeln(data);
            iframedoc.close();
            //page loaded at this point
        } else {
            alert('Fail to get the content windows');
        }
    }
```

Reference: http://thinkofdev.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe/